# Make Subsite visible to others

Tags: office-365, sub-site, public-website

In Office 365 I created a new "subsite" with a URL like `https://mySite.sharepoint.com/mySubwebSite`.
Is it possible to place it next to the other websites, like in the following picture?

[image: Screenshot]

The only way I found out so far is to send an invitation to my collegues so that it appears at their "website I follow" section.

Comment: Have you tried adding those users into the site members group?

Comment: Yes, those users all are members of the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go with Admin account into the O365 administration page, go to Sites, then click Manage. You can add a link to your subsite and give it a name you need.

Have a look at the image below, you can add links to external sites as well.

[image]